# Angular Using interpolation to reading a string value that has another interpolation

Tags: angular

I have a json file with an array of properties called title, most are string values which I got the Angular HTML to read into the title UI.

So, if the JSON field has a string, the title will be correctly interpolated and displayed in the button. It is working.

But if I have a string varible, called "title" in the TS code, I have a string value that has another interpolation to read from the TS code. I having no luck to get this to work.

Any help is great. Thanks

JSON file

```
export const data= [
    {
        title: 'My Title'
    },
    {
        title: '{{updatedTitle}}'
    }
];
```

HTML:

```html
<div *ngFor="let info of data">
    <button 
     title="{{info.title}}"> 
    </button>
</div>
```

In my TS code, title can be assigned to any value based on a condition.

When I load the UI, the button does not show up with the title. Been googling with no success. Thanks.

Comment: thre're **no** interpolation in .ts, you're saying that title becomes the **string** `{{updatedTitle}}` not the value of the variable `updateTitle`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pipe that takes the `title` as value.

In the pipe you can check if the value is encapsulated in double braces. If not you return the originally received value like `'My title'`, otherwise remove the double braces and replace the value with the desired title.

Comment: Can you post example code? Thx

Answer (score -1):

Actually interpolation stated as a string when you use in the double quote.
If you want to make dynamic updated title then you have to use

```
<div *ngFor="let info of data">
    <button [innerHtml]="info.title">
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not even valid angular template code

Comment: This was for sure. <button [innerHtml]="info.title"></button>